# Wordpress Filter by Tag with Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm setting up a P2 themed (using Houston child theme) Wordpress. I want to accomplish the following but after hours and hours of searching I cannot figure out how to do this even though it seems like something that would be common.

Ideally, I would like a tag list in the sidebar with checkboxes for each tag. Only posts that match checked tags are displayed and it updates with Ajax rather than a page reload. It saves what you have checked to the user profile (page will require login).

I would settle for simply having a tag list/cloud that would update with Ajax if I could also have links that would display multiple tags. It's no problem if I have to hard code these tag-grouping links.

Basically I want users to control what posts they are interested in reading, the assumption is no one will be reading every post, just the tags that pertain to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I was able to find was this plugin:

Cat + Tag Filter

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cat-tag-filter-widget/

And configuring it for checkboxes on tag. It doesn't reload with Ajax or remember what the user selected, but it does take you to a tag filtered page that you could bookmark.